# $X$ is $T_0$ $\;\Longleftrightarrow\;$ $\overline{\{x\}} \neq \overline{\{y\}} \; \forall x\neq y$

Tags: general-topology

Alredy proved/known:

$x\in A' \Longrightarrow (U-\{x\})\cap A\neq\emptyset \;\forall \;U\in\tau$

$x\in\overline{A} \Longleftrightarrow U\cap A\neq\emptyset \;\forall\; U\in\tau \;\; x\in U$

Hint for $X\in T_0\Longrightarrow \overline{\{x\}}\neq\overline{\{y\}}$ please

I've solved $\Longleftarrow$ implication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be $T_0$ and $x_0 \neq x_1$. By being $T_0$ there is an open set $U$ that contains exactly one point of $\{x_0,x_1\}$ say $x_i$. This open $U$ is then a neighbourhood of that $x_i$ that is disjoint from $\{x_{1-i}\}$ so $x_i \notin \overline{\{x_{1-i}\}}$, while trivially $x_{i} \in \overline{\{x_{i}\}}$, so $\overline{\{x_{i}\}} \neq \overline{\{x_{1-i}\}}$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, very useful